# Converting date/time in YYYYMMDD/HHMMSS format to Python datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I have a date in YYYYMMDD format and a time in HHMMSS format as strings in the 4th and 5th elements in a list.  I.E.:

```
data[4] = '20100304'
data[5] = '082835'
```

I am creating an instance of datetime (in a field named generates) like this:

```
generatedtime = datetime.datetime(int(data[4][:4]),int(data[4][4:6]),int(data[4][6:]),int(data[5][:2]),int(data[5][2:4]),int(data[5][4:6]))
```

Given that the input format cannot change, is there a cleaner way I should be creating my instance of the datetime object?

Comment: Your code, while awkward looking, does the job nicely.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

No need to import `time`; [`datetime.datetime.strptime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) can do it by itself.

```
import datetime
dt=datetime.datetime.strptime(data[4]+data[5],'%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
print(dt)
# 2010-03-04 08:28:35
```

For information on the format codes (e.g. `%Y%m%d%H%M%S`) available, see the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-behavior) for `strftime`.

Comment: If the timestamp is not specified, the time will be treated as local time. The following example converts a UTC time to Unix timestamp: `datetime.datetime.strptime(timeval, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S").replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).timestamp()` (I actually use this for parsing a FTP MDTM response)

Answer (score 8):

You might take a look at [time.strptime](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strptime).

```
import time
time.strptime('20100304 082835', '%Y%m%d %H%M%S')
```

The above assumes a 24-hour clock (`%H`).  Use `%I` instead if using a 12-hour clock.

For a complete list of available format directives, check out the docs for [time.strftime](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strftime)

Answer (score 0):

You could clean up your existing code a bit with a generator (equivalent to a map):

```
generatedtime = datetime.datetime( *(int(x) for x in
   (data[4][:4], data[4][4:6], data[4][6:], data[5][:2], data[5][2:4],data[5][4:6])
   ) )
```

or even, if you're crazy like a fox, you could make the datetime statement even cleaner (at the expense of adding a ridiculous line):

```
slices = ( (4, slice(4)), (4, slice(4,6) ), (4, slice(6,None)), (5, slice(2) ), (5, slice(2,4) ), (5, slice(4,6)) )
generatedtime = datetime.datetime( *(int(data[i][s]) for (i,s) in slices) )
```